# Android HERE map SDK won't download map tile using Emulator

Tags: android, ssl, sdk, certificate

I was working on HERE map android SDK and I am using my Emulator. I am in a corporate environment with an issue of connecting to secured web services. Log is saying that certificate is not found. Any workaround for this? Thanks!

Emulator settings:

> API 21
>   CPU/ABI = X86
>   TARGET = Android 5.0.1

Exception:

> D/com.here.android.mpa.internal.cc: FileNotFoundException : while deserializing object. | /data/data/com.userspace/app_Archive/mapIndex: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> D/com.here.android.mpa.internal.cc: FileNotFoundException : while deserializing object. | /data/data/com.userspace/app_Archive/MapViewStateDetails.archive: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> E/com.here.android.mpa.internal.bu$b: IOException : while creating server connection. | java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. for URL: https://2.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/9/131/190/512/png8?app_id=id&app_code=code&lg=eng&lg2=dut

Comment: [Update cacert.bks](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/setting-up-a-persistent-trusted-ca-in-an-android-emulator/)  - i got this link and this works for lower versions of sdk's. Is there any other way aside from doing this?

Comment: I believe emulators are not supported by the SDK https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/system-requirements.html

Comment: @JithinKrishnan i am using none native libraries so this should work for starter kit.